# Jquery select object by id dynamically using a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image gallery that uses modals. In the image modal or outside it, the user can click on a star and mark the image as favorite. Favorite images have a class that makes the star change color its to 'golden'. If a user marks a favorite in the modal, I need to change the color of the star of that image outside the modal as well.

To do this, I thought I could have a

```
<p id = "modal_counter" class = "hidden">number</p>
```

in the modal, so that I can get the image number. Then I use that image number as part of a jquery selector.

The images in the gallery have something like this:

```
<p id = "image_number" class = "hidden"></p>
<!-- for example: <p id = "image_2"  class = "hidden"></p> -->
```

So, all I need is to successfully select the hidden p tag next to each image, then I could use jquery's next() or parent().find().

This is the relevant code:

```
...
var modal_counter = div_parent.find('#modal_counter').text();
var counter = "#image_"+String(modal_counter);

/* I would like the counter to be something like "#image_2" */

var $(counter).parent().find('.star').addClass('golden')
...
```

This doesn't work. Jquery tries to find an object using this selector:

```
"#image_\n 2"
```

and of course, it doesn't find one. I tried removing the \n with a regex, but it still doesn't work:

```
counter_processed = modal_counter.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Comment: id attributes are supposed to be unique in the page. Something is causing the newlines to be inserted: http://jsbin.com/dayoja/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll probably be better to use a `data-attribute` on your element rather than getting the text content. Do:

```
<p id = "modal_counter" class = "hidden" data-counter="number">number</p>
```

Then you can:

```
...
var modal_counter = div_parent.find('#modal_counter').data('counter');
var counter = "#image_" + modal_counter;

/* I would like the counter to be something like "#image_2" */

var $(counter).parent().find('.star').addClass('golden')
...
```

This way you don't bind your javascript to the text inside your elements.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a handy `trim` function:

```
var modal_counter = div_parent.find('#modal_counter').text().trim();
```

Try this from your console:

```
$.trim("\n\nHello\r\nThere\n")
```

See how it removes the leading and trailing white-space?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have:

```
<p id="modal_1" class="hidden">Img 1</p>
```

you can extract the number both using:

```
// If you need it from the text
var n = $("[id^=modal_]").text().match(/\d+/); // 1
```

or

```
// If you need it from the ID
var n = $("[id^=modal_]")[0].id.match(/\d+/);  // 1
```

Than to target the image like:

```
<img id="image_1" src="someimage.jpg" alt="SEO">
```

you do:

```
$('#image_'+ n)
```

---

If you really just have:

```
<p id="modal_counter" class="hidden">3</p>
```

than you can do:

```
var n = $('#modal_counter').text();  // "3"
$("#image_"+ n)                      // .fadeIn() or whatever...
```

Just make sure you don't have duplicate `modal_counter` ID elements on your page. ID has to be unique.